# Conditional Formatting Formula for Duration

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, excel-2016

```
Start Duration  1  2  3  4  5  7  8  9  10  ...
1     5
4     5
4     8
10    8
10    2
15    22
```

Is there a formula I can use similar to something like this? `=AND(C$1>=$A2, C$1<=B2)`
It's like a gantt chart

Comment: Can you be more specific ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
=AND(C$1>=$A1,C$1<=$A1+$B1-1)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I feel stupid this is very simple math :D
But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply formula to conditional formatting,just select

1. New Formatting Rule
2. Use a formula to determine which cells to format

[image]